# Filling in the Categorical NaN value by NA and the Numerical NaN by 0

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a very large data set. There are a lot of categorical and numerical variables. Also there is a lot of NaN values in both of them. Is it possible to replace the Categorical NaN's by NA and the Numerical NaN's by 0 in the entire data frame. I know the fillna command to Replace NAN Values in the entire data frame. But have no idea about this one.

Comment: Do you have an example of categorical NaN and numerical NaN? Please post a minimal example.

Comment: from pandas doc, df.replace({'A': {0: 100, 4: 400}}) is an example to replace certain value (np.nan in your case) to something else if you know 'A' is either numerical is catogorical. You just need to construct the right dictionary for replace function